# Secondary SSD with data files, programs not able to Read/Write from this disk

Tags: 18.04, mount, hard-drive, filesystem

I migrated my W10 laptop (Asus Zenbook UX310ua) to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, everything works in terms of driver support.  But I'm having issues reading/writing from the files I had on a secondary SSD from the W10 time.  I had this partition in NTFS changed it to EXT4 (backed up all the data prior to doing this and made sure no file got corrupted), even changed the path of the "Documents, Pictures, etc." directories to this partition where I already hosted such type of files.  However, everytime I try to open a file from an application, say LibreOffice Calc with a spreadsheet I get an error message with "/path/to/file does not exist."
I can see the disk and the partition I created with **lsblk** here is the output

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    ...
sda
└─sda1                  8:1    0 931,5G  0 part /Data
sdb                     8:16   0 119,2G  0 disk 
├─sdb1                  8:17   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2                  8:18   0 118,8G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root   253:0    0 117,8G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:1    0   980M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

I've modified the disk to mount on /Data everytime on boot.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `ls -la /Data` shows what?

Comment: @AlexP shows all my folders with drwxrwxrwx permits, no hidden folders

Comment: And if you try to `cd` to the file in question and then open it (from the command line) with `xdg-open`, does LibreOffice Calc still  complain?

Comment: So you can see files in nautilus, but unable to open them with LibreOffice?

Comment: @AlexP tried the `xdg-open` still the same error

Comment: @AlvinLiang yes, happens not only with LibreOffice but with other programs as well (inkscape with SVG files, etc)

Comment: Ok...let me guess...You replaced built-in LibreOffice with latest snap one?  And Inkscape is also from snap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using snap packages, this is a snap limitation. Snap softwares are confined to your home dir.

If you connect your software with `removable-media` interface, it will be allowed to access `/media/* and /run/media/*`.

So you can connect your software to `removable-media` interface and change your mount point to where it can access.  For example, /media/Data

command:
`sudo snap connect libreoffice:removable-media`

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/libreoffice-snap-cant-find-my-other-hard-disk/6456